Pass the field parameter of the current class in the constructor of the current class to the constructor of the parent class
Is it possible to pass the ‘this.lst’ field in the Test1 class constructor to the Test class constructor (without making the ‘lst’ field static)?
class Test
{
    internal Test(List<int> lst)
    {
        lst.Add(1);
    }
}

class Test1 : Test
{
    private List<int> lst = new();

    internal Test1() : base(this.lst)
    {

    }
}


Updated question
Code:
class NodeListService<T> where T : NodeWrapper
{
    private List<T> lst_node = new();
    internal IList<T> ElementsList
    {
        get => this.lst_node.AsReadOnly();
    }

    internal NodeListService(List<Node> lst_ext_node, Func<Node, T> create_node)
    {
        //loop by list
        foreach (Node cur_node in lst_ext_node)
        {
            T cur_node_wrapper = create_node(cur_node);
            this.lst_node.Add(cur_node_wrapper);
        }
    }
}

class NodeListService1 : NodeListService<NodeWrapper1>
{
    private IDGenerator id_generator = new();

    internal NodeListService1(List<Node> lst_ext_node) : base
    (
        lst_ext_node,
        cur_node =>
            {
                NodeWrapper1 cur_node_wrapper = new((Node1)cur_node);
                this.id_generator.AddID(cur_node_wrapper.ID);//not allowed
            }
    )
    {
        //you can do it this way, but it will be the second loop on nodes after the loop in the NodeListService constructor
        foreach (NodeWrapper1 cur_node_wrapper in this.ElementsList)
        {
            this.id_generator.AddID(cur_node_wrapper.ID);
        }
    }
}

class NodeListService2 : NodeListService<NodeWrapper2>
{

    internal NodeListService2(List<Node> lst_ext_node) : base(lst_ext_node, cur_node => new NodeWrapper2((Node2)cur_node))
    {

    }
}

#region Node
//The Node, Node1 and Node2 classes are external implementations that I can't change
class Node
{
}

class Node1 : Node
{
    internal int ID;

    internal Node1(int id)
    {
        this.ID = id;
    }
}

class Node2 : Node
{
    internal readonly int OtherField;

    internal Node2(int other_field)
    {
        this.OtherField = other_field;
    }
}
#endregion

#region NodeWrapper
//NodeWrapper1 and NodeWrapper2 classes are my wrappers to work with Node1 and Node2 classes respectively
//They inherit from the NodeWrapper class, as they both need access to the NodeValue field
class NodeWrapper
{
    protected readonly Node NodeValue;

    internal NodeWrapper(Node cur_node)
    {
        this.NodeValue = cur_node;
    }
}

class NodeWrapper1 : NodeWrapper
{
    internal readonly int ID;

    #region ctor
    internal NodeWrapper1(Node1 cur_node) : base(cur_node)
    {
        this.ID = cur_node.ID;
    }
    #endregion
}

class NodeWrapper2 : NodeWrapper
{
    internal readonly int SomeOtherField;

    internal NodeWrapper2(Node2 cur_node) : base(cur_node)
    {
        this.SomeOtherField = cur_node.OtherField;
    }
}
#endregion

class IDGenerator
{
    private int counter = 0;
    private HashSet<int> hs_used_id = new();

    //If a new Node1 (and NodeWrapper1 for it) is to be created, a sequentially increasing ID must be generated
    internal int GetNewID()
    {
        while (hs_used_id.Contains(this.counter++)) ;
        return this.counter;
    }

    internal bool AddID(int id) => hs_used_id.Add(id);
}

There are external classes Node1 and Node2 for which it is necessary to create wrapper classes NodeWrapper1 and NodeWrapper2, and classes NodeListService1 and NodeListService2 for managing the list of objects NodeWrapper1 and NodeWrapper2 respectively
The NodeWrapper1 class has an ID field that should be read and added to the list of used IDs
The list of used IDs is stored in the IDGenerator class object in the id_generator field of the NodeListService1 class
The NodeListService class creates a list with wrappers in the constructor using the ‘create_node’ delegate
Now to read IDs in the constructor of the NodeListService1 class and add them to the list of used IDs, I have to make a second loop through the wrapper nodes created with the ‘create_node’ delegate (accessed via the ElementsList property)
To avoid the second loop I wanted to pass the id_generator field of the NodeListService1 class to the ‘create_node’ delegate
But this causes error CS0027
Is it possible to add the used IDs to id_generator without using the second loop?

This is kind of a weird constructor setup in the first place.  Why is Test requiring and modifying a list in its constructor, but not using that input to construct anything of itself?  For the functionality shown, I would make the Test constructor a method instead, and just call that method in the Test1 constructor.

Yepp. Its a bad example. I would also just say don't do it this way. To suggest something better we need a better example. I would make a lst a member of Test and just set it in the Test1 constructor.

This question is similar to: C#: Why can't I pass 'this' as a constructor argument to a base class?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Is it a theoretical question?
class Test
{
    protected List<int> lst = new();

The solution can be to put lst into the base class. It will be accessible in all descendants.
It's difficult to suggest more because the question is very exempt.
